# Possible to create 'hidden' calendar items to display notification alarms in iPhone app?

Tags: objective-c, notifications, push-notification, ekeventkit, ekevent

I am working on an app that incorporates user-generated events. As the app currently stands, the option to add the event to the user's calendar is optional (and this should not change, because the event could already be on the calendar from somewhere else).

I want to give the users the option to be notified before their event from the app in any case. Obviously, if the user has selected to add the event to their calendar, the best way (I believe) would be to use the alarms for the calendar event.

However, is this option available for an event if the user does not add it to their calendar? I would still like to give them options for notification... I guess I am asking - is there a way to create a 'hidden' calendar event, just for the use of the app, and use it to send the alarms the user sets up in the app?

It seems like this would be so much more straightforward than setting up push notifications. Any thoughts on the subject, or how I could approve my approach, would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use local notifications which are like push notifications but don't require a server. These are available in OS4+.

Here [is a tutorial on using them.](http://blog.corywiles.com/uilocalnotification-example-project-using-ios)

Comment: Thanks. I had forgotten about local notifications. But, I assume there are no hidden calendar event options? My issue is then, when there are only calendar events for some items, is it best to just scrap the calendar alarms and user local notifications for every event regardless of calendar status? To keep things neat and pretty I want to do every notification one way or the other - I don't want to have two types of notifications.

Comment: This is correct, you can't hide calendar entries from users so if consistency is important to you then you will need to go 100% down the local notifications route.